# jQuery $function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

```
<html>
      <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
      <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
      <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function () {           
           alert("Test");
      });

      </script>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

If i will call `$(document).ready(function (){ });` function after jquery script. Then it is working. But with above case, it is not working and Firefox console debugging getting

`ReferenceError: $ is not defined`
Firefox Version =31.0
Please can someone help to resolve this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you need to run the jquery before loading jquery?

Comment: I read that $(document).ready(function (){ }); will be called after loading DOM. So it should work. why is not working?

Comment: I recommend to read the jQuery tutorial: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Answer (score 2):

Browser will compile line by line in the order you defined your statements. So, you need to include your jquery library before using its functions.

That's it.

Comment: I read that $(document).ready(function (){ }); will be called after loading DOM. So it should work. why is not working?

Comment: @Manku are you aware of the fact that `$(document).ready(` is a jquery function? So if you specify it before adding `jQuery` library, the browser doesn't know what it is and throws error. It is called after `DOM` is ready, but is *compiled* before that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you should include JQuery(jquery-2.1.1.min.js) before function runs.

```
<html>
      <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
      <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {           
           alert("Test");
      });  
      </script>

</html>
```